# App validation error, CloudKit entitlements error

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, provisioning-profile, cloudkit

I have made an app with CloudKit support, the app works fine at testing it retrieves the records from iCloud, and add new records. When I archive the app and click validate I saw the following error:

`No matching provisioning profiles found for Applications/aplicationname.app
None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specific entitlements:
com.apple.developer.icloud-containers-identifiers, beta-reports-active,
com.apple.developer.icloud-services.`

I read following at Apple Developer:

*"Before you ship your app, configure your app using the distribution workflow. In this workflow, Xcode lets you choose whether you want to target the development or production environment and adds the com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment entitlement to your app with the value you selected. Prior to shipping, be sure to configure your app for the production environment. Apps that target the development environment will be rejected by the App Store."*

I think it's solution, but can't find the way from where I have to do this.

Comment: I found where from i can choose target development or production but it seems my problem presents before the option of target environment.
Does anyone knows where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I went to the developers portal and at the provisioning profiles, i created a profile for distribution, i choose the app with the problem, and i generated the profile. After the profile created i download it, and run it.
After that when i check validate it found the missing profiles and validated my app correctly.